# How to know if a vector is in a subspace spanned by a set of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have $v_1=(1,0,-1),\; v_2=(2,1,3),\; v_3=(4,2,6)\; \text{ and}\; w=(3,1,2),$ 
where $v_1,v_2,v_3\;$ and $w$ are all column vectors.
I want to know if $w$ is in the subspace spanned by $(v_1,v_2,v_3).$

I write down:

$$\begin{aligned}x_1+2x_2+4x_3&=3\\x_2+2x_3&=1\\-x_1+3x_2+6x_3&=2\end{aligned}$$

And I augment it to get

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 4 &3 \\
    0 & 1 & 2&1 \\
    -1 & 3 & 6& 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Now, from what the professor told us, I should row reduce it to get

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 4 &3 \\
    0 & 1 & 2&1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

And this is my first question : why should I row reduce it only to the last row being all $0$'s?

Moreover, On the book it states :

> Since the dimension of the space of the columns of the augmented matrix
>   coincides with the dimension of the space of the columns of the matrix
>   of the coefficients, the system admits a non-trivial solution, and $w\in
> Span \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}.$

Since I have a form of dyscalculia this statement appears unclear to me. Could somebody please explain in simple words what this means?

What do they mean when they say the dimension of the space of the columns of the augmented matrix coincides with the dimension of the space of the columns of the matrix of the coefficients? Why does this imply that the systems admits a non trivial solution ? What is the non trivial solution here?

If you could help me please please please explain it in the simplest way possible....Thanks for the help guys! You are great.

Comment: Build your matrix by rows, i.e.: take the transpose of your matrix, and now reduce it by rows. Then $\;w\in\text{Span}\,\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}\;$ iff the last row becomes all zeros. In this particular case, since $\;v_1,v_2,v_3\;$ are **not** linearly independent, they do not form a basis of $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ and it is thus not guaranteed $\;w\;$ is a linear combination of them...

Comment: Is it necessary to take the transpose? Can't i just row reduce it ? How do i know when  i should stop row reducing?

Comment: What does it mean that the dimension of the space of the columns of the augmented matrix
coincides with the dimension of the space of the columns of the matrix
of the coefficients?

Comment: The reduction ends when your matrix reaches an echelon form, i.e.: when it is "as diagonal" as possible. This you achieved when the last row became all zeros (this is **not always** the case, though). Observe that it is clear that once the first column plus once the second column eplux zero the third one equals the fourth column. But imo it is easier to do this with the vectors as *rows*, and not columns, and reducing by rows: if you this you'll get the last two rows become all zero, which mean those two vectors represented by those rows are lin. comb of the first two.